# check if already logged in, in other app

Tags: node.js, drupal

I have two application running in the server. One in Apache server where my main website is running & other in Nodejs for my chat application. If the home page of my chat application is opened (opens in a new tab), how to identify if the user has already logged in,  through the website

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new window of the chatbox would be initialisng on a button click or something from the website . Just pass extra para from the website like token or email id  to create a session at chat application